# Load file in other folder using system.file

Tags: r, xls

I want to load xlsx file using `system.file` in other folder. The default folder is the root folder of xlsx. But I want to load the files in `"G:\data\file\2017\summer.xls"`.

How can I change the default folder?

Answer (score 0):

Using setwd("Folder direction") will make the directory you entered in the parameter the default.

Comment: I have tre it, but it seems not useful

Comment: @DXL, because any of the more expert people answered you question, I will still try to help you. But, it will be some speculation. If G is an external drive, R maybe don't have the capability to use it. At least C, if the file is in an external drive, it cannot be compiled. Also, did you received any error message after changing the working directory?